# Computer shut downs automaticly

Tags: laptop, windows-10-v1511

I have windows 10 64bit and facing a big problem with my laptop when on Battery power. firstly the situations in which the problems occured.

1. when i am on Battery and playing games or running any graphics intensive App the temp of my GPU i.e Intel HD Graphics reaches 72 celsius or around this Laptop turns off suddenly. No proper shut down just whole laptop turns off.

2.Also when battery reaches 26% same problem occured.

3.All these problems do not occured when i am on AC power.

I have researched many times on RAM Temp, CPU Temp and Gpu Temp

But after doing stress test on my Video card i am able to know that when ever the GPU temp reaches More than 65 or 75 degree celsius la[top just turns off Immidiately.

But before this My GPU reaches 89 degree C. and all the things running well on Battery power as well as AC power. But this time don`t know what had happened, strange thing is  that on AC power why laptop does`t shut down all the things runs well on AC power.
Please help. How to fix it?

Comment: Does the battery get hot when it happens?  Have you really verified the GPU temperature when running on AC?

Comment: Yes, Some times battery gets hot when this thing happens but also in sometimes when laptop turns off battery is cool.

Comment: Did you check the CPU temperature in both cases?  There may be some power management options that change the system's behavior when running on the battery that could perhaps explain the weirdness.

Comment: On battery power i have run stress test for hours but notting happens maximum temp of my CPU was 80 degree celsius

Comment: Just to be sure:  The GPU temperature gets higher when running on the battery?  If so, is the CPU temperature lower than when plugged in?

Comment: no cpu temp remians constant between 40 c and 80 C not more but  know   when ever intel hd graphic reached 72C just  laptop turn off.earlier i faced nothing like this when GPU TEMP is high

Comment: You might want to check the BIOS configuration for power management to see if there are rules relating to the GPU temperature but this is really strange.  I feel I'm missing a small detail to clarify the issue.

Comment: I have checked the bios but there is no power management option or related options

Answer (score 0):

You have a faulty cell in your battery - Replace as soon as you can as the problem will get gradually worse. If an original battery from the manufacturer is too expensive, go for the pattern replacement battery on ebay but only get one that has a three year warranty.